# How do I limit the number of records sent to the reducer in a map reduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have an file with over 300000 lines that's an input to a map reduce job and I want the job to process only the first 1000 lines of this file. Is there a good way to limit the number of records sent to the reducer?

A simple identity reducer is all I need to write out my output. Currently, the reducer writes out as many lines as there are in the input.

Comment: why do you need a map/reduce program if you just want to process just 1000 lines- just write a simple program that scans through the 1000 lines and be done with it

Comment: It entirely depends on the logic that you need to perform and the input files. If you have a file with millions of data and need as small as thousands of line, better filter off the unwanted ones with Pig or perform a hive aggregation on the data set.

Comment: Unless they are extremely long lines, I would just use "head -n 1000 input > output" to grab the first thousand lines (or "hadoop dfs -text input | head -n 1000 > output" if the file is in HDFS). Honestly, Arnon's suggestion to simply not use MR makes a lot of sense. 1000 lines is very small.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure your mapreduce program is set to only use one reducer. It has to be explicitly set, otherwise Hadoop might choose some other number, and then there's no good way to coordinate between reduce tasks to make sure they don't emit more than 1000 total. Then you can simply maintain an instance variable in your Reducer class that counts how many records it has seen, and stops emitting them after 1000.

The other, probably simpler, way to do it would be to shorten your input file. Just delete the lines you don't need.

It's also worth noting that hive and pig are both frameworks that will do this type of thing for you. Writing "raw" MapReduce code is rare in practice. Most people use one of those two.

Comment: Joe, could you throw some light on "setting reducer count explicitly". So far I was of the belief that reducer count is restricted to "ONE" unless and until set explicitly by the user. Mapper count purely depends on the number and size of files.

Comment: Yes, actually, I think I was wrong. It appears hadoop's default is always one.

However, I do think that any time you have code that depends on the number of mappers or number of reducers, it's a good idea to set it explicitly and document it.